# On forget password: this error occured "Email can't be blank"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i got this error on `forget password.` how to fix it. and i want to customize it. i need to reset password through `email` as well as `username` also.
my model is as following

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  belongs_to :role
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :confirmable, :lockable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]
  # validates_uniqueness_of :username
  # validates_presence_of   :username

  after_create :create_profile



  attr_accessor :login

  def create_profile
    if self.role.name == "student"
        Student.create :user_id => self.id
      elsif self.role.name == "company"
        Company.create :user_id => self.id
      else
        University.create :user_id => self.id  
    end    
  end

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: What is that 1 error? Should we guess?

Comment: @rustam------- now check it, thanks for mention it

Comment: The relevant code is missing - what is the controller code? are you trying to save a user without entering an email? Is the email field mandatory?

Comment: maybe read some documentation https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address and derive ideas